Intermittent SSL cURL error 35 in production environment
I'm encountering an intermittent SSL error in our production environment that’s causing significant issues. Here are the details:
Exemple:
[2024-07-08 17:50:06] production.ERROR: cURL error 35: OpenSSL/1.1.1w: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://backend/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Description:
This error occurs randomly throughout the day and lasts for random durations (from 1 to 10 minutes). When it happens, it affects all routes, making the backend inaccessible. We’ve attempted to bypass SSL (using the without verifying param from laravel) certificate verification for our routes, but this hasn’t resolved the issue.
Additional Information:
The error is not correlated with peak usage times of the application.
We are using OpenSSL 1.1.1w.
The application is operated over a shared hosting
Steps Taken:

Attempted to disable SSL certificate verification in our routes – no success.
Checked server logs and monitored network traffic for any unusual patterns.
Renew SSL Certificate (which wasn't outdated)

Despite these efforts, the error persists. Any insights or suggestions to diagnose and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!

have you done as suggested in the link ? "CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35):
A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. You really want the error buffer and read the message there as it pinpoints the problem slightly more. Could be certificates (file formats, paths, permissions), passwords, and others." so check the error buffer and act to resolve it or at least post the error details in here

Any received alert cannot be caused by local cert verification so changing or disabling that verification is useless. Most causes of this alert are on the remote server and can neither be identified nor fixed nor mitigated on your client, so you should be asking the server admin(s) what their system says is wrong.

What curl version do you use?
